# Making floated text break off onto the next line

Tags: css

How do I make this:

[image]

break off onto the next line like this?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/06ewqwun/

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <h1>Test test test test</h1>

  <!-- This div has to be here -->

  <div>
    <p>Another test another test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test { border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; }
h1 { float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; }

/* Has no effect */

p { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oh ya `break off onto the next line like this?` is doubtful. that's why I asked

Comment: Mark, why using a `DIV` than to wrap your `P` element?

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/06ewqwun/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to stick with that HTML structure, you could try this:

You can use and play with CSS `line-height` property on your container div

like:

```
.YOURDIVCLASS{
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

You might also want to reset the h1 tag's default padding and margin.

```
h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**[HERE'S A SAMPLE IN jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/06ewqwun/3/)**

Comment: Thanks. I normally wouldn't wrap the `p` in a `div` but there's some extra functionality going on that I felt wasn't necessary to include.

Comment: Found a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013861/floating-next-to-headline-once-headline-breaks-off-into-two-lines -- could be cool if you could drop by.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make the elements `inline` you can try to reset the margins.

[image: Result]

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, voluptates.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 320px;
}

.box h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
}

.box p {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/xaL7sarm/.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the `h1` inside your div:

```
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <h1>Test test test test</h1>
      <p>Another test another test, and a bit more test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/06ewqwun/2/)