# Floating next to headline once headline breaks off into two lines

Tags: css

Expanding on [Making floated text break off onto the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441497/making-floated-text-break-off-onto-the-next-line) which basically produces this:

[image]

How does one retain the float of the paragraph once the headline gets a little bit longer?

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/06ewqwun/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <h1>Test test test test test test</h1>
    <div class="another">
        <div class="subanother1">
            <p>Another test another test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
h1 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.another {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Interested to know the answer!

Comment: Can't we adjust the html structure?

Comment: I'm afraid not. It's due to some extra functionality that I felt was unnecessary to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `.another` , `.subanother1` and `p` to `display: inline` will solve the problem.

[**check the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/06ewqwun/13/)

```
.another, .subanother1, p {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Looks good :) How do you feel it compares to Alex's answer? Having trouble deciding which to accept =/

Comment: I just changed 1 line only from your code. Anyway both will solve your problem. :) It's up to you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add `display: inline-block` to `.subanother1` class:

```css
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
h1 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.another {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.subanother1{
    display: inline-block;/*Add display inline block*/
    line-height: 0em;/*Set line hight to 0em*/
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <h1>Test test test  Test test test</h1>
    <div class="another">
        <div class="subanother1">
            <p>Another test another test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! How do you feel it compares to Libin's answer though?

Comment: I think i answer a bit earlier :)

Comment: You sure did :) But both look equally neat. Having a bit of a dilemma here.

Comment: Really sorry bro. Had to think long and hard. In the end Libin's was less code and I got to reuse the same property so.. I really appreciate it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `width` of elements like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/06ewqwun/10/).

Comment: Thanks, but the headline should not have a fixed width. Updated the question with the desired result.